# Logging into CSV file not working with log4j-core and log4j-api version 2.17.2

Tags: java, csv, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am developing a logger to log into a csv file and onto a console. I was previously using log4j-core and log4j-api version 2.6.2. But due to restriction issues i had to upgrade to version 2.17.2

Earlier it was working perfectly, but after upgrading the version, it is not creating a file, it is just logging directly onto console. Can anyone help me with this ?

This is my dependency in pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
        <!-- <version>2.6.2</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
       <!-- <version>2.6.2</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="csvLog.fileName">csvLog</Property>
        <Property name="file-header">sender,flow,message</Property>
        <Property name="baseDir">logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="csvFile" 
                     fileName="${baseDir}/csvLog.csv"
                     filePattern="${baseDir}/csvLog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.csv">
            <CsvParameterLayout delimiter="," header="${file-header}\n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
             <!--   <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" /> -->
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
               <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="1">
                  <IfFileName glob="csvLog*.csv" /> 
                  <IfLastModified age="2m" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="CSVLOG" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="csvFile" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="debug"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is my main file:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ObjectArrayMessage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;


@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class App {
 private static final Logger csvlogger = LogManager.getLogger("CSVLOG");
 private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

 public static void main(String args[]){

     SpringApplication.run(App.class);
     
     csvlogger.info("Debug Message", "Namaste", "Whats up", "hmm..ok");
     logger.info("You have made an error");
     logger.debug("Debug Message");
     
     runMe("test");
 }
 
 private static void runMe(String parameterParam){
     String parameter;
     for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
         parameter = parameterParam + i;
         System.out.println("log iteration: "+i);
         if (csvlogger.isDebugEnabled()) {
             csvlogger.debug(new ObjectArrayMessage("JD", "Ri", parameter));
         }

         if (csvlogger.isInfoEnabled()) {
             csvlogger.info(new ObjectArrayMessage("JD", "Ri", parameter));
         }

         csvlogger.info(new ObjectArrayMessage("JD", "Ri", parameter));
         csvlogger.info(new ObjectArrayMessage("JD", "Ri", parameter));
         csvlogger.info(new ObjectArrayMessage("JD", "Ri", parameter));
         try {
             Thread.sleep(60000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
 
}
```

Can anyone guide what changes to do with this updated version & how to make it work ?

Comment: *<Property name="csvLog.fileName">csvLog</Property>* looks wrong to me. Should be more like `<Property name="csvLog.fileName">"${baseDir}/csvLog.csv"</Property>` Make sure all derivations of that are correct. You should build on property `$csvLog.fileName`

Comment: Hi @g00se thanks for the comment but actually that property is not the issue. After changing the log4j core and api version I am getting issues. It was working fine before I changed the versions.